# Signature Verification of transaction executed on Payment Gateway in NodeJs

Tags: python, node.js, payment-gateway, cryptojs, hmac

How do I implement the below python/Java/PHP code in NodeJs?

[ReferenceLink](https://docs.cashfree.com/docs/android-sdk#verify-signature)

Python Code (for reference):

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64

@app.route('/notify_url/', methods=["POST"])
def notify_url_process():

 postData = {
  "orderId" : request.form['orderId'], 
  "orderAmount" : request.form['orderAmount'], 
  "referenceId" : request.form['referenceId'], 
  "txStatus" : request.form['txStatus'], 
  "paymentMode" : request.form['paymentMode'], 
  "txMsg" : request.form['txMsg'], 
  "txTime" : request.form['txTime'], 
 }

 signatureData = postData["orderId"] + postData["orderAmount"] + postData["referenceId"] + postData["txStatus"] + postData["paymentMode"] + postData["txMsg"] + postData["txTime"]

 message = bytes(signatureData).encode('utf-8')
 #get secret key from your config
 secret = bytes(secretKey).encode('utf-8')
 signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(secret, 
   message,digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest())
```

So far, I was able to come up with the below code. However, the generated and received signatures do not match.

```
var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', "appSecret"); //Key hidden for posting here
hmac.update(request.body.orderId + request.body.orderAmount+request.body.referenceId+request.body.txStatus+request.body.paymentMode+request.body.txMsg+request.body.txTime);
let generatedSignature = hmac.digest('hex');
let isSignatureValid = generatedSignature == request.body.cashfreeSignature;

console.log(isSignatureValid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried comparing the base64 encoding as opposed to the hex value?

Instead of

```
let generatedSignature = hmac.digest('hex');
```

use

```
let generatedSignature = hmac.digest('base64');
```